# Accessing a dynamic content switcher from another page

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors

I want to be able to access the dynamic content on the Menu page from every other page on the website but with the code below,  it doesn't even leave the current page when clicked on. I'd like it to display the exact content that was clicked on. The contents to be displayed are all on the menu page. The URL is http://www.pizza.siteripe.com/menu.html  I can't tell what the problem is.

```
   <script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() {
    jcps.fader(300, '#switcher-panel');
});


</script>
```

Comment: What is your problem? Could you describe what happens and what *should* be happening?

Comment: When any of the links from the menu on the sidebar is clicked on (from other pages), it should take you to the menu page while displaying the exact content that was clicked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to redirect somehow and show the content:

```
$('#introright a').click(function() {
  if (window.location.href != 'http://www.pizza.siteripe.com/menu.html') {
    window.location.href = 'http://www.pizza.siteripe.com/menu.html#' + $(this).prop('id');
  }
});
```

Then on the `menu.html` page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (window.location.hash) {
    $(window.location.hash).click();
  }
});
```

I wrote this from memory so don't expect it to work. But you might get lucky.